# Did you know you can ignore tags?

Tags: discussion, tag

Some topics, while on-topic for the site, might not be suitable for all users.  For example, at some point, you may not be keen on [dream](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dream) questions popping up in your feed.  It's actually possible to **ignore questions with this tag**.

I'm posting this in case (a) users might not be aware that this is a feature; (b) it might help users have a better experience; and (c) another [alternative to arguing in comments](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/the-many-alternatives-to-arguing-in-comments).

1. On the main site, hover over the tag with your cursor, which brings up this menu:

   [image]
2. Click the star twice to turn it into a red cross:

   [image]

   (Clicking it once makes it a favourite; twice and it's ignored; and three times and it goes back to normal.)
3. By default, this will gray out those questions.  To ignore the totally, go to your [preferences](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/preferences) page and click "Hide questions in your ignored tags":

   [image]

Afterwards, questions with those tags are no longer displayed, and this pops up at the bottom of the front page:

[image]