# Lots of questions are inappropriate and having/regarding the adult content?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Not feeling like visiting the site anymore as its having lots of questions being asked on adult content or sexuality on daily basis, and almost all the questions are duplicate. many are inappropriate and haven't heard before if read mind gets disturb. And these are from new users.

We should not entertain this on the site as its a community driven site and its for learning more about Islam and its teachings. I know that those are also very important to learn but it should not spoil this site as many questions are being asked on that only.

I saw on an average 3 out 10 are inappropriate.

few links [1](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43139/please-be-specific),[2](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/how-can-i-understand-that-my-girl-is-satisfied-in-sex-any-islamic-tips),[3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43132/what-should-i-do-to-help-a-helpless-women),[4](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43130/can-i-do-anything-with-my-wife) asked in a single day :(

I think we should have a question sandbox for all the new questions from new users and it should be gone through it before appearing in the main site.so that we will have only good quality posts.

Please put your suggestions and opinions on this.

Comment: "We should not entertain this on the site as its an Islamic site" - This is not an Islamic site, it's a site about Islam. There is no presumption of Islam being correct or authoritative in its teachings on the SE network or Islam.SE.

Comment: I really don't see any need for adding a "sandbox" feature; most of this *can and should* already be handled by proper voting and basic site curation. If the community is failing in this, there's nothing to suggest they'll be any better at processing a sandbox queue.

Comment: @G.Bach, I know this is not an Islamic site, there are many out there though and which has lots of  presumption of Islam being correct or authoritative in its teachings, this is a community driven site to know more about Islam and its targeted towards specific religious(Islam) community and for the people who are interested to know about Islam but according to SE network on each site we have some kind of rules to avoid off topic questions and low quality posts  that is what I want to address it here.

Comment: And yes if you feel that `There is no presumption of Islam being correct or authoritative in its teachings` you can open a thread on SE :)

Comment: "its targeted towards specific religious(Islam) community" - No, it isn't, it's targeted to people who want reliable information about Islam.

Comment: @G.Bach, hmmm thats true.., but anything those questions as just spams and doesn't fit here

Answer (score 3):

Islam.SE an "Islamic" site in the sense that we learn about Islam here---it's not an online mosque.

However, I agree that there's many questions about the OP's masturbation, fornication, ultra-specific sex acts, etc., which are both off-topic ([counselling](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/868/17163) or [peer support](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/17163); and often don't have an [attitude of detachment](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/islam-stack-exchange-is-not-for-debates-or-apologetics)) and off-putting to the users.  Furthermore, such questions encourage other such questions.

Keep in mind that not all "adult" posts are like this.  (Think pornography vs. sex education.)

A partial solution is to ignore tags; see [Did you know you can ignore tags?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1906/17163).  But it doesn't really stop the inflow.

We can discourage these posts e.g. by:

- We can downvote.
- We can vote to close (or flag to get others to vote to close).  Ideally we should be getting close votes within minutes of them being posted.
- We can comment to explain one's personal "adult" issue is not an appropriate topic for the site.
- Don't answer them; the users probably don't care about the site and "reputation", but they care about the answer.
- Keep the front page looking professional by improving [question titles](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1837/17163), so these questions look out of place.
- Keep active in producing suitable questions (and answers to questions).

With the example questions given, this is mostly what has happened.  If they're closed (not as duplicate) and downvoted, they'll end up automatically deleted.

(Recently I've been editing away the [haram](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haram) tag; perhaps bumping these questions has encouraged this behavior, and it may not continue after the retagging has finished.)

> I think we should have a question sandbox for all the new questions from new users and it should be gone through it before appearing in the main site.so that we will have only good quality posts.

We have the [Review queues](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review) for this purpose.  (First Posts---Review first posts from new users.)  StackOverflow has [Triage and Help and Improvement queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) to help with this problem, but it's not network-wide.

We're not capable of changing the site mechanics here, that's what [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is for.  (But I don't recommend making a feature request there until you're very familiar with the StackExchange software [etc.].)

Comment: "We're not capable of changing the site mechanics here, that's what meta.SE is for" <-- not entirely true; the devs can still modify site mechanics if there's a clear and pressing need demonstrated on just one site. meta.SE is great to demonstrate that it's a clear an pressing need on *multiple* sites though, which significantly increases the chances of being taken seriously.

Comment: I agree with your suggestions but all of those will not remove the post from appearing on the main site and we will end up with lots of spam and off-topic questions. And though it will not see in my home page due to my preferences but others can see it.

Comment: I think this we should do this `Keep the front page looking professional by improving question titles, so these questions look out of place`. and also the `question body`