# A sign of becoming a mature site: questions are being closed without diamond moderator intervention

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

**Questions are being closed without diamond moderator intervention**.  (See the search [`closed:true`](https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3Atrue) sorted by newest for examples.)  This is an essential part of self-moderation (which I consider an [obstacle to graduation](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/some-obstacles-to-graduation-self-moderation-question-inflow-upvotes-and-exp)); see also [A guide to self moderation -- help moderate Islam.SE](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/650/17163).

This is happening a lot now:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(As the 5-th vote, the vote to close on the last question would have closed the question without the "diamond hammer".)

There's nine users listed in those examples above.

---

There's other promising signs I've been seeing:

1. regular high-quality answers, sometimes even competing with one another (as described on the [tour page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour));
2. rubbish posts being downvoted;
3. users are leaving "how to fix this post"-style comments (they're [constructive](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/what-makes-a-comment-constructive));
4. users seem to be becoming more welcoming to and tolerant of new users.

(Maybe these need individual "pat ourselves on the back" meta posts.)

---

I think this calls for a round of applause:

[image]

(Random [uncopyrighted](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Defense.gov_News_Photo_000519-D-9880W-201.jpg) image I found at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page).)

Comment: Related but less visible, spam/offensive posts are disappearing a lot faster too ([Charcoal/SmokeDetector](http://charcoal-se.org/) takes a lot of credit for that, but flags from local users are definitely speeding up that process)